# How to resolve aliased text in MFC controls

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+, antialiasing

I'm currently in the second stage of development for a data management project I'm involved with; at the moment, we're in the stage of revamping the GUI (we're going for an office 2007-themed GUI).

At the moment I've only got experience with Dialog-based MFC projects, from which this migrates from, where we drew controls onto the dialog, then got handles to them using the `GetDlgItem` command, using the IDs of the controls.

Now, we're using SDI, instead of a dialog-based project, and thus, it's required to procedurally create the controls. I've had no problems creating and showing controls in the `ChildView` area; however, the text is very low quality and aliased. I googled the problem, but was unable to find anything particularly pertinent to the problem, indeed, the only thing which bore any real relevance was using GDI+ to draw anti-aliased text, which is fine for simple text, but I need MFC controls such as `CEdit` and `CListBox`.

Here is an image to help illustrate my problem:
[image]

I am creating both the static GDI+ text and the MFC control in the `OnPaint` function, as follows:

```
void CChildView::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(dc);

    static Gdiplus::FontFamily* fontFamily = new Gdiplus::FontFamily( _T("Segoe UI") );
    static Gdiplus::Font* font = new Gdiplus::Font( fontFamily, 12, Gdiplus::FontStyle::FontStyleRegular, Gdiplus::Unit::UnitPixel );
    static Gdiplus::SolidBrush* solidBrush = new Gdiplus::SolidBrush( Gdiplus::Color::RoyalBlue );

    Gdiplus::PointF point( 10, 10 );
    graphics.SetTextRenderingHint( Gdiplus::TextRenderingHint::TextRenderingHintAntiAlias );
    graphics.DrawString( _T("Hello, World!"), 13, font, point, solidBrush );

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    CEdit* pEditBox = new CEdit();
    pEditBox->CreateEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("EDIT"), _T("Why is this text so poor?"), WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(100, 100, 300, 200), this, UINT_MAX-9 );


    // Do not call CWnd::OnPaint() for painting messages
}
```

At the moment, I am wondering if it necessary to derive each of the controls and change their rendering methods to use GDI+ antialiased text. Hopefully their is an easier way to resolve this problem.

I will be extremely grateful for any help/advice.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just for reference, I used to following to resolve my problem:

```
    CFont* pFont = new CFont();
    pFont->CreatePointFont( 120, _T("Segoe UI") );
    CEdit* pEditBox = new CEdit();
    pEditBox->CreateEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("EDIT"), _T("Test Edit"), WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(100, 100, 300, 200), this, UINT_MAX-9 );
    pEditBox->SetFont( pFont );
```

Alternatively, the following allows for the default font for the window to be used:

```
CEdit* pEditBox = new CEdit();
pEditBox->CreateEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("EDIT"), _T("This text is no longer poor"), WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(100, 100, 300, 200), this, UINT_MAX-9 );

if( ::IsWindow( pEditBox->GetSafeHwnd() ) )
{
    ::SendMessage( pEditBox->GetSafeHwnd(), WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)(HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), FALSE );
}
```

Comment: Change the font. See e.g. `SystemParametersInfo` with `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS` argument if you want to get the "normal" font.

Comment: Try changing the edit boxes font with it's CWnd::SetFont() method. Good luck.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, it appears just changing it to Segoe UI improves the quality drastically. Thanks! :)

Comment: I've posted it as an answer, so that you could accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the font used by the edit box, it's just the default one that looks so ugly.

If you want to get the "standard" font, see e.g. `SystemParametersInfo` with `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS` argument. Of course, you can use any other font if you want to.